# AWK or SED, retrieve values from string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to retrieve couple of values from a string (output from *iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i quality*).

```
Link Quality=37/100  Signal level=57/100  Noise level=0/100
```

I need the **37** from *Link Quality=37/100*, **57** from *Signal level=57/100* and **0** from *Noise level=0/100*.
It doesn't have to be in the same command. What I'm trying to do, is post those values to MQTT server using mosquitto_pub.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[=/]' 'tolower($0) ~ /quality/{print $2, $4, $6}' file
37 57 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```bsh
iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i quality | grep -oP '\d+(?=/)'
```

which outputs

```
37
57
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numbers of interest always come before '/100', you could grep for
'some number' followed by '/100' and then cut everything up to the '/':

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\/100' your_file | cut -d/ -f1
```

This gives the output:

```
37
57
0
```